# Convert a string type (Jun 22 2021 1:04PM) to a timestamp of type "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a" in PysSpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Pyspark

I am trying to convert a string with value Jun 22 2021  1:04PM to a timestamp using the below code block but its making the value as null, where as its showing the datatype is timestamp

```
df = df.withColumn("date", F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp("date","MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),'yyyy-MM-dd').cast('timestamp'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `date` is of the format `MMM d yyyy hh:mmaa`

To convert a string like above format. Do like below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.withColumn("date_2", f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp("date", 'MMM d yyyy hh:mmaa'),'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
df=df.withColumn("date", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("date"), "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),"yyyy-MM-dd")).show(false)
```

Comment: Hey I have already tried the above method, it makes the values NULL, is there anything I can try ?